# Distribution of quadratic form?

Tags: regression, distributions, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, quadratic-form

Let $\mathbf{y = X \boldsymbol{\beta} + \epsilon}$, where $\mathbf{X} \in \mathcal{R}^{N\times p}$, $\boldsymbol\beta \in \mathcal{R}^p$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \sim N(0,\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}_N)$. Let $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ and $\hat{\epsilon}$  denote the fitted and residual vectors corresponding to the least squares estimate of  $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. 
Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathcal{R}^{p \times q}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{y}}_r$  denote the fitted vectors corresponding to the least squares estimate of  $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, subject to the restriction that $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in \mathcal{C(\mathbf{A})}$.

If $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in \mathcal{C(\mathbf{A})}$, identify $s$ and $d$ and find the distribution of $$Q=\dfrac{(\|\hat{\mathbf{y}}\|^2 - \|\hat{\mathbf{y}_r}\|^2)/s}{\| \mathbf{\hat{\epsilon}}\|^2/d }$$

I think that this will follow an F-distribution. I did the following:

1. $\hat{\mathbf{y}} \sim N( \boldsymbol{X\beta},\sigma^2 \mathbf{PP}')$, where $\mathbf{P = XGX'}$
2. $\| \mathbf{\hat{\epsilon}}\|^2 =SSE \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{N-rank(P)}$

Should d be $N-rank(P)$?

Any help regarding this will be useful.